# How to view the content of a resultset in Toad from a stored procedure with unknown number of columns?

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, toad

In Tsql I can execute a stored procedure in Query Analyzer and view the content of a resultset right there query analyzer window without know anything about the query structure (tables, columns, ...)

--Tsql sample
exec myproc parm1, parm2, parm3

Now I am working with PLsql and Toad (which I am relatively new at for Toad).  I need to view the content of a resultset of a convoluted stored procedure, and I don't know what the number of columns is -- let alone their data types (this proc is composed of several freaky subqueries -- which I can view individually, but they get pivoted, and the number of columns varies in the final resultset).  How can I view the content of this resultset in Toad when I execute the procedure when I don't know how many columns there are or their data types?

Below is code that I have mustered together for viewing the content of a result set of stored procedures where I know how many columns there are and their data types ahead of time.  In my code sample below I use a sys_refcursor that I named x_out and I also create a temporary table to store the content of the resultset for additional viewing.  Is there a way I can do this when I don't know how many columns there are in the resultset?  How to do this with PLsql -- Toad?

```
create global temporary table tmpResult (fld1 number, fld2 varchar(50), fld3 date);

declare
  x_out sys_refcursor;  
  tmpfld1 number;
  tmpfld2 varchar2(50);
  tmpfld3 date;

BEGIN
  myschema.mypkg.myproc(parm1, parm2, x_out);

LOOP
    FETCH x_out INTO tmpfld1, tmpfld2, tmpfld3;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line ('fld1:-- '||tmpfld1||': fld2:-- '||tmpfld2||':   fld3:-- '||tmpfld3);

-- I also insert the result set to a temp table for additional viewing of the data from the stored procedure

    Insert Into tmpResult values(tmpfld1, tmpfld2, tmpfld3);        
    EXIT WHEN x_out%NOTFOUND;    

END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: What version of Toad?

Answer (score 0):

Toad can automatically retrieve the cursor for you. You have a few options, #3 perhaps is the easiest if you just want to see the data.

1. If you have the myschema.mypkg loaded in the Editor you can hit <kbd>F11</kbd> to execute it. In the dialog that shows select your package member to the left and select the Output Options tab. Check the option to fetch cursor results or use the DBMS Output options. Click OK and the package executes. Depending on your Toad version you'll see a grid at the bottom of Editor for your results or you'll see a PL/SQL results tab. If you see the latter double click the (CURSOR) value in the output column for your output argument. I suggest using the fetch option as long as your dataset isn't so large that it will cause Out of Memory errors.
2. Locate your package in the Schema Browser and rt-click, Execute Package. You'll see the same dialog as mentioned in #1. Follow the remaining steps there.
3. Use a bind variable from an anonymous block. Using your example you'd want something like this...

   `declare
     x_out sys_refcursor;
   begin
     myschema.mypkg.myproc(parm1, parm2, x_out);
     :retval := x_out;
   end;`

Execute this with <kbd>F9</kbd> in the Editor. In the Bind Variable popup set the datatype of retval to Cursor. Click OK. Your results are then shown in the data grid. Again if your dataset is very large you may run out of memory here.

Comment: Excellent!   I found one other way to do this -- not as cool as your way, but an option (this one doesn't do the pivoting)

Comment: Excellent.  I found one other way -- trying to post it.

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow not letting me post this other solution:

I try posting part of this other solution (if SOF lets me) - this the 2nd half of the other way:

```
BEGIN 
myschema.mypkg.myproc(parm1, parm2, parm3 x_out); 

FOR rec_ IN get_columns LOOP 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(rec_.name || ': ' || rec_.VALUE); 
END LOOP;   
END;
```

Comment: Is it a link to another site? I don't know why it wouldn't let you post, but I know that just posting links to other sites is strongly discouraged. For instance there are some blogs out there suggesting to use the SQL*Plus "print" command, but for a single statement execution using Toad's script engine is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

and here is the 1st half of the other way:

```
DECLARE 
x_out SYS_REFCURSOR; 

CURSOR get_columns IS
```

...

Comment: here's another part of the 1st half --- SELECT t2.column_value.getrootelement()         name, 
             EXTRACTVALUE(t2.column_value, 'node()')  VALUE

Comment: and here is near the last part of the 1st half of the other way ---

Comment: I seem to be having a problem posting the expression xmlsequence(x_out) but that is what the other way uses to do a similar content read of a cursor

Comment: Unless you have a need to use the results in your PL/SQL or you just want to write the code manually I'd let Toad handle it automatically if viewing the data is your only goal. I assume you purchased Toad to make your life easier, after all!

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the cursor to ":data_grid" in order to show SP result in Toad Data Grid pane.

**Call Store Procedure in PL/SQL Script:**

> Run with F9 not F5

[image]

Toad is the best I know when it comes to DB IDE.

**Press "F9" and bind it**. That is all

[image]