# How to Call Procedure and Output Results in a Grid

Tags: plsql, toad, oracle11gr2

I would like to execute the following procedure using TOAD. I would like the results of the procedure call to be output into a grid within the TOAD UI. The procedure itself is inside a package named `MyPackage`. The package creates a type called `ct`.

Type:

```
TYPE ct IS REF CURSOR;
```

Procedure Code:

```
PROCEDURE GetFailedTransactions (p_fails OUT ct)
IS
BEGIN
    OPEN p_fails FOR SELECT *
                     FROM MDC_FAILURE
                    WHERE SUCCESS_DT IS NULL;
END;
```

Comment: See... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658248/how-to-view-the-content-of-a-resultset-in-toad-from-a-stored-procedure-with-unkn/35659494#35659494. Check out my answer. Option 1 and 2 will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:my_out_cursor` will prompt for the variables dialog box. Set the type of the variable to `cursor` and the direction to `OUT`. Then the output will appear in the grid section.

```
BEGIN
MyPackage.GetFailedTransactions(:my_out_cursor);
END;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like the answer the poster was looking for.

Comment: @JohnFoll I was the poster.